# NSWindow in front of every app and in front of the menu bar Objective-c Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, window, nswindow, menubar

How can I make my NSWindow appear in front of every app and the menubar? I also don't want a title bar on my window. Just a fullscreen app without the dock menubar and not in apple's fullscreen mode.
I can get my window above all of the other apps and dock like this:

```
[window setLevel:kCGPopUpMenuWindowLevel];
```

but it doesn't cover the mac menubar.

Comment: Can you move it behind the menu bar? Or can you just not move it higher that the menubar?

Comment: @DrummerB      I can't move it behind the menubar of in front of the menubar. The menubar is like a barrier.

Answer (score 7):

You can't move a default window higher that the menu bar, because it's constrained. You have to subclass NSWindow and override `constrainFrameRect:toScreen:`

```
- (NSRect)constrainFrameRect:(NSRect)frameRect toScreen:(NSScreen *)screen {
    return frameRect;
}
```

Comment: How can I subclass an NSWindow?

Comment: [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1)

Comment: Paste it where? Did you subclass NSWindow?

Answer (score 2):

Set the window level to `NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 2`.

If you use `NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 1` the top menu bar will still appear sometimes but is very unpredictable. `NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 2` forces it to stay above the menu bar and keep focus permanently.

```
[window setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 2];
```

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3:

```
window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.mainMenuWindow)) + 2
```